# Django model related field set

Tags: django

I've got a small problem I can't seem to figure out.

I've got the following model:

```
class UserWhale(models.Model):
    currencyPair = models.ForeignKey('currencies.CurrencyPair', verbose_name='Currency Pair')
    currency = models.ForeignKey('currencies.Currency', verbose_name='Source Currency')
    currencyTarget = models.ForeignKey('currencies.Currency', related_name='whale_currency_target_rel', verbose_name='Target Currency')
    userBankAccount = models.ForeignKey(UserBankAccount, verbose_name='Deposit Bank Account')
    whale_fee_percentage = models.DecimalField(max_digits=11, decimal_places=2)
    whale_amount = models.DecimalField(max_digits=11, decimal_places=2)
    whale_matched = models.DecimalField(max_digits=11, decimal_places=2)
    priority = models.IntegerField()
    user = models.ForeignKey('auth.User', related_name='whale_relation_user', editable=False)
    created_by = models.ForeignKey('auth.User', editable=False)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, editable=False)
    modified = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, editable=False)
    history = audit.AuditTrail()
```

When I output the following:

```
{{ request.user.userwhale_set.count }}
```

It always outputs as zero even tho the current user has data in that table. The "user" and "created_by" fields are always different so I'm wondering whether or not the code above is using the "created_by" relationship instead of the "user" relationship. If so, how do I specify which one to use?

Many thanks
Ben.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have specified the `related_name` property on the `user` foreignkey, so you should call that name: `request.user.whale_relation_user.count`.